# FlutterFlow / Flutter - Widget passing JSON data to blackoutDates in Syncfusion date picker

Tags: flutter, date, datepicker, syncfusion, flutterflow

I have the following custom widget in FlutterFlow

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/datepicker.dart';

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class DateRangePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const DateRangePicker({
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.jsonDataRaw,
    this.simpleText,
  });

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final dynamic jsonDataRaw;
  final String? simpleText;

  @override
  State<DateRangePicker> createState() => _DateRangePickerState();
}


class _DateRangePickerState extends State<DateRangePicker> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(widget.simpleText.toString()),
          //Text(widget.jsonDataRaw.toString()),
          SfDateRangePicker(
            view: DateRangePickerView.month,
            monthViewSettings: DateRangePickerMonthViewSettings(
                firstDayOfWeek: 1,
                blackoutDates: [
                  DateTime(2024, 03, 18),
                  DateTime(2024, 03, 19)
                ]),
            monthCellStyle: DateRangePickerMonthCellStyle(
              blackoutDateTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red, decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
            ),
            selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
            enablePastDates: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Where here I have a result - widget.jsonDataRaw:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "error": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "01/03/2024",
      "iso_date": "2024-03-01T18:50:01.672Z",
      "utc_date": "Fri, 01 Mar 2024 18:50:01 GMT",
      "date_string": "Fri Mar 01 2024",
      "timestamp": 1709319001672,
      "status": "owner"
    },
    {
      "date": "02/03/2024",
      "iso_date": "2024-03-02T18:50:01.672Z",
      "utc_date": "Sat, 02 Mar 2024 18:50:01 GMT",
      "date_string": "Sat Mar 02 2024",
      "timestamp": 1709405401672,
      "status": "owner"
    },
    {
      "date": "03/03/2024",
      "iso_date": "2024-03-03T18:50:01.672Z",
      "utc_date": "Sun, 03 Mar 2024 18:50:01 GMT",
      "date_string": "Sun Mar 03 2024",
      "timestamp": 1709491801672,
      "status": "owner"
    },
    {
      "date": "04/03/2024",
      "iso_date": "2024-03-04T18:50:01.672Z",
      "utc_date": "Mon, 04 Mar 2024 18:50:01 GMT",
      "date_string": "Mon Mar 04 2024",
      "timestamp": 1709578201672,
      "status": "owner"
    },
    {
      "date": "11/03/2024",
      "iso_date": "2024-03-11T18:50:01.672Z",
      "utc_date": "Mon, 11 Mar 2024 18:50:01 GMT",
      "date_string": "Mon Mar 11 2024",
      "timestamp": 1710183001672,
      "status": "reception"
    },
    {
      "date": "12/03/2024",
      "iso_date": "2024-03-12T18:50:01.672Z",
      "utc_date": "Tue, 12 Mar 2024 18:50:01 GMT",
      "date_string": "Tue Mar 12 2024",
      "timestamp": 1710269401672,
      "status": "reception"
    },
    {
      "date": "13/03/2024",
      "iso_date": "2024-03-13T18:50:01.672Z",
      "utc_date": "Wed, 13 Mar 2024 18:50:01 GMT",
      "date_string": "Wed Mar 13 2024",
      "timestamp": 1710355801672,
      "status": "reception"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where I am trying to replace the hardcoded data with that of the JSON response.

I have the date in several formats, but every time I try to submit it I get various errors. I would be grateful if someone could help me solve this case

```
blackoutDates: [
                  DateTime(2024, 03, 18),
                  DateTime(2024, 03, 19)
                ]),
```

Where I am trying to replace the hardcoded data with that of the JSON response.

I have the date in several formats, but every time I try to submit it I get various errors. I would be grateful if someone could help me solve this case

```
blackoutDates: [
                  DateTime(2024, 03, 18),
                  DateTime(2024, 03, 19)
                ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the hardcoded blackout dates value in the field, then parse the JSON string from the constructor to iterate the date values from it and add them to the blackout dates field. Then Wrap the [SfDateRangePicker](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/latest/datepicker/SfDateRangePicker-class.html) widget inside the future builder and set the found blackout dates value to the [blackoutDates](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/latest/datepicker/DateRangePickerMonthViewSettings/blackoutDates.html) property in the [DateRangePickerMonthViewSettings](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/latest/datepicker/DateRangePickerMonthViewSettings-class.html).

have modified your sample based on your requirements and shared it below, you can refer to it and achieve your requirements.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/datepicker.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(CalendarApp());
}

class CalendarApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Calendar Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
      home: const DateRangePicker(jsonDataRaw: 'assets/data.json'),
    );
  }
}

class DateRangePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const DateRangePicker({
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.jsonDataRaw,
    this.simpleText,
  });

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String jsonDataRaw;
  final String? simpleText;

  @override
  State<DateRangePicker> createState() => _DateRangePickerState();
}

class _DateRangePickerState extends State<DateRangePicker> {
  List<DateTime> blackoutDates = <DateTime>[
    DateTime(2024, 03, 18),
    DateTime(2024, 03, 19)
  ];

  Future<String> getJsonFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(widget.jsonDataRaw);
  }

  Future loadSalesData() async {
    final String jsonString = await getJsonFromAssets();
    final dynamic jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    blackoutDates.clear();
    for (Map<String, dynamic> i in jsonResponse['data']) {
      blackoutDates.add(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(i['timestamp']));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadSalesData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: getJsonFromAssets(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return SfDateRangePicker(
              monthViewSettings: DateRangePickerMonthViewSettings(
                firstDayOfWeek: 1,
                blackoutDates: blackoutDates,
              ),
              monthCellStyle: const DateRangePickerMonthCellStyle(
                blackoutDateTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                ),
              ),
              selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
              enablePastDates: false,
            );
          } else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Very much and thank you!
Do you have any idea How to prevent selection before and after blocked days?